# no funciona el setAdapter(arrayAdapter) en esta linea de codigo

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

no me funciona esta linea de codigo en el setaAdapter y no se por que?

```
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_data)
    val pais = resources.getStringArray(R.array.paises)
    val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,pais)
    editTextTextPais.setAdapter(arrayAdapter)
    btnSigu.setOnClickListener {
        val intent: Intent = Intent(this, DatosPersonales::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El EditText no admite adapters, si quieres mostrar sugerencias de texto puedes usar AutoCompleteTextView.

```
val list=ArrayList<String>()//Aqui va tu lista de sugerencias
        list.add("Hola")
        list.add("Hola2")
        list.add("Hola3")
        list.add("Adios")
        list.add("Kotlin")
        val customAdapter=CustomAdapter(this@KotlinActivity,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list)
        customAdapter.onItemClickListener=object:CustomAdapter.OnItemClickListener{
            override fun onItemClick(value:String?) {
                Toast.makeText(this@KotlinActivity,"Item: $value",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(customAdapter)
```